# Who says "what you mustn't do in politics is listen to people" in the On The Hour introduction?

Tags: united-kingdom

In the [introduction to radio news satire On The Hour](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EVgz9oeVdrY), who says "what you mustn't do in politics is listen to people."? Is it John Major?